# Returning a data object from state - Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'll preface this by saying it's only my second day working with react and I'm no expert in coding either. I would appreciate any answers to this to be explained as such. Any and all responses are however greatly valued.

I am trying to understand the relationship between the state and render(). I have defined a data object called `myDataObj`. The App component grabs some variables in the constructor. I create a variable called `someData` which takes a dataobject and `myVar` which is an integer. The render function is executed the first time. Each of my console.logs are logged to the console. The componentDidMount function is then executed after the render, then the render is ran again due to the setState method.

My question is why can I not get the two lines that I have commented out to pull the value from the state? I am able to directly access those variable (within scope) by referencing them directly: `myDataObj.myData[0]`. I can access the `myVar` variable via the state as shown in `this.state.myVar`.

When trying to push a new item into myDataObj via `someData.myData.push({name:'Item 4'});` I get a 'someData' is not defined.

When trying to log the first element of the variable via `{console.log(this.state.someData.myData[0])}` I get a 'Cannot read propert '0' of undefined.

Hopefully I was able to articulate the problem correctly. The code is below.

Thank you

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

let myDataObj = {
  myData: [
    {name:'Item 1'},
    {name:'Item 2'},
    {name:'Item 3'}
    ]
};

let myVar = 2


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {someData: {}, myVar}
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      myVar = myVar + 1;
      myDataObj.myData.push({name:'Item 4'});
      // someData.myData.push({name:'Item 4'});    this doesn't work... 'someData' is not defined
      this.setState({someData: myDataObj, myVar});

  }
  render () {
    return(
      <div className="App">
        {console.log(myVar)}   {/* Logs a 2 then 3 */}
        {console.log(this.state.myVar)}   {/* Logs a 2 then 3 */}
        {console.log(myDataObj.myData[3])}   {/*Logs undefined then 'Item 4' */}
        {/* {console.log(this.state.someData.myData[0])} */} {/*TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Error explains it, doesn't it? You are accessing something, that is not yet defined. Your render happens when `this.state.someData = {}` is an empty object, yet you are accessing property that does not exists (`myData` is undefined) and further `[3]` of `undefined`. First you should check if prop exists.. and look at React docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are declaring variables outside the class and then using it as its state. I would do like :-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      myData: [{name:'Item 1'},
        {name:'Item 2'},
        {name:'Item 3'}], 
      myVar : 2}
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      //myVar = myVar + 1;
     // myDataObj.myData.push({name:'Item 4'});
      // someData.myData.push({name:'Item 4'});    this doesn't work... 'someData' is not defined
      this.setState({myData: [...this.state.myData, {"name" : 4}], 

    myVar : this.state.myVar + 1});

  }
  render () {
    return(
      <div className="App">
        {console.log(this.state.myVar)} 
        {console.log(this.state.myData[3])} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I guess I decided to declare them outside the class in case I added another component which would want to access the same variable? Since this comment answered the question and was first, I will mark it as answered. Thanks

Comment: your welcome. If you really want to make a global variables so that another components can access those variables, I am using redux for that. You might want to take a look. If you need help in that case let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to checkout React's component lifecycle. [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

ComponentDidMount get's executed after mounting, e.g. after the component has been rendered once. During your first render `this.state.someData.myData` is undefined. Accessing a property of undefined results in a TypeError.

Move your variable directly to your state:

```
this.state = {
      myData: [
        {name:'Item 1'},
        {name:'Item 2'},
        {name:'Item 3'}
      ], 
      myVar : 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and help. I am checking out the link. As I said in the other comment, I was thinking that I may want another component to access the variable as it was initialized. But maybe that is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

About your first log statement, `someData` is undefined because it is a state variable so it needs to be accessed as `this.state.someData`. Still pushing items directly into the state is not a good practice. Just for the sake of your log statement, your state needs to be initialized like i have done below for it to run correctly.

```
 this.state = {
    someData: {
        myData: []
    },
    myVar
 }
```

This should solve your second log statement as well. Your state needs to be initialized as above if you want to log `this.state.someData.myData[0]` on your first render because `myData` array inside someData is not defined until your `setState` in componentDidMount runs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Appreciate the advice on the best practices.